# How to allow dot character in hql search string?

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // setters and getters
}
```

1:

```
    List<Tag> tags = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery("from Tag as t where t.name=:name",Tag.class)
                    .setParameter("name", "Mr.John")
                    .getResultList();

             if(tags == null || tags.isEmpty())
              System.out.println("Did not find Result");
             else
              System.out.println("Found Result");
```

prints:

```
Did not find Result
```

2:

```
List<Tag> tags = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from Tag as t where t.name='Mr.John'",Tag.class)
                .getResultList();

         if(tags == null || tags.isEmpty())
          System.out.println("Did not find Result");
         else
          System.out.println("Found Result");
```

prints:

```
Found Result
```

Note not using setParameter produces the correct result

How can I allow dot character in hql search string while using setParameter to protect against SQL Injection?

Ps: I am using Hibernate 5.2.6

Answer (score 1):

But in my code it works fine in both cases:

**1) Using SetParameter():**

```
 List<Book> list = entityManager.createQuery("from Book b where b.name=:nm").setParameter("nm", "Mr.Angad").getResultList();
if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("Record not found :( ");
else
    System.out.println("Record found :) ");

o/p: Record found :)
```

**2) Without SetParameter:**

```
  List<Book> list = entityManager.createQuery("from Book b where b.name='Mr.Angad'").getResultList();
if(list == null || list.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("Record not found :( ");
else
    System.out.println("Record found :) ");

 o/p : Record found :)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK. You are already protected against sql injection because you are setting those params through Session interface methods. Your query will be evaluated as HQL if something it is wrong an exception will be thrown, so an sql injection can't occurs. An sql injection would be concatenate (string concatenation) those parameters to an native (calling createSQLQuery method) sql query

use setString btw.

Comment: 1- hql doesn't protect against sql injection see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hibernate                                                                          2- setString is deprecated and doesn't work

Comment: by doesn't work I mean produces the same result as setParameter

Comment: I didnt say that Hibernate completely protects you against sql injection and I wrote about native sql. I'm using Hibernate 5 and setString it is not deprecated (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-).

Comment: take a look to this post https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/

Comment: you are right... since hibernate 5.2 we must use setParameter